# MLE of $N(\theta,a\theta)$ family

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

A special case of a normal family is one in which the mean and variance are related, the $N(\theta,a\theta)$ family. If we are interested in testing this relationship, regardless of the value of $\theta$, we are again faced with a nuisance parameter problem.

Find the LRT of $H_0: a =1$ versus $H_1: a \neq 1$ based on a sample $X_1,...,X_n$ from a $N(\theta, a\theta)$ family, where $\theta$ is unknown.

I'm ok in terms of finding the Likelihood Ratio Test, but I'm having trouble with the restricted MLE.

So far I have

$$\frac{\partial log L}{\partial \theta} = \frac{-n}{2\theta}+\frac{1}{2a\theta^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\theta)^2+\frac{n\bar{x}-n\theta}{a\theta}=0$$

Setting $a=1$ and solving for $\theta$ I have

$$\bar{x}^2- \theta - \theta^2 = 0$$

However, the solution is

$$\hat{\theta}_R = \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4(\hat{\theta}^2+\hat{x}^2)}}{2}$$

Comment: where does such a problem show up, could you please exaplain a bit? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"Setting $a=1$ and solving for $\theta$" actually yields $$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2=\theta+\theta^2.$$

Comment: Interesting, because they are basically the same. They solved for the quadratic, so I guess both work?

Comment: No, yours is wrong because $(\bar x)^2\ne\bar{x^2}$.